# How to hide a curve tail of a bubble chat box while gradient background colour using CSS only

Tags: html, css

[image: How I hide the white space of this image using css ?]

How to hide a curve tail of bubble chat box while different background color using css ?

```css
body {
  background: #1e5799; 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #2989d8 50%, #7db9e8 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#2989d8 50%,#7db9e8 100%); 
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#2989d8 50%,#7db9e8 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 ); 
}

.speech-bubble {
  position: relative;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: .4em .4em .4em 0;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-shadow: 0 -0.05em 0.1em rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.speech-bubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-right: 25px solid #ddd;
  *background: #00aabb;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 80px 50px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 80px 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80px 50px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  transform: rotate(-181deg) translate(-35%, 97%);
}

/* creates part of the curved pointy bit */
.speech-bubble:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: 100%;
  width: 21px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 40px 50px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 40px 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px 50px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
  -moz-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
  -ms-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
  -o-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0%, -97%);
}
```

```html
<div class="speech-bubble"></div>
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: @Sfili_81, Actually I cant able to paste my code, and I follow this link, Please check this link , 6th image from bottom.
http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

Comment: @Sfili_81 , Please find my code in above, I just shared.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, the best way is to use photo shop and alter the image. You can maybe find a css Hack involving having a div with position and z-index sitting on top of the white corner...but that will be an ugly solution to a simple problem. Just find a better image or alter it yourself in photoshop or the like.

Comment: I need to do it by using css not photoshop

Answer (score -1):

Just change it's `background` color to match the one of the `body` *element*:

```css
:root {
  --bgc: #ece8e8; /* defined background color */
}

body {
  background: var(--bgc); /* used here */
}

.speech-bubble {
  position: relative;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: .4em;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-shadow: 0 -0.05em 0.1em rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.speech-bubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-right: 25px solid #ddd;
  *background: #00aabb;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 80px 50px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 80px 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80px 50px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  transform: rotate(-181deg) translate(-35%, 97%);
}

/* creates part of the curved pointy bit */
.speech-bubble:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: 100%;
  width: 21px;
  height: 30px;
  background: var(--bgc); /* and here */
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 40px 50px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 40px 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px 50px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
  -moz-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
  -ms-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
  -o-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0%, -97%);
}
```

```html
<div class="speech-bubble"></div>
```

Preferably done with *CSS Variables* to make it *dynamic* so that you don't have to check if the two match or change it twice, while you can do it once on the `:root` *element* and be sure.